# Cron job script doesn't upload file on my ftp server?

Tags: ftp, php, cron, upload

I am using php script to upload file on some ftp server. 
When I start my script through browser it is working fine, but when the script is running as cron job script doesn't upload file on my ftp server.

What are the differences between running script from browsers and as cron job ? 
How can i solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: test script as cron maybe some path problems.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with